# Pivot a Pandas DF (Explode the column values to multiple columns)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am trying to flatten the file data using pandas.

```
input=[['','','','Actual','Forecast'],['','','','Jan','Feb'],['A','B','Personal','10.00','1.00'],['A','B','Operational','20.00','2.00']]
```

```
df=pd.DataFrame(input,columns=['Div','cc','expense_type','Col1','Col2'])
```

My input looks like the snippet shown.
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwCGh.png)

And my output should look like the snippet below shown.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkwUO.png)

Can anyone help me to solve this use case using pandas. Thanks.

Comment: post your input as dict . it will be help to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `melt` method in pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html. If you share a data dictionary, I can make some example code for you.

#### EDIT

```
import pandas as pd
data =[['A','B','Personal','10.00','1.00'],['A','B','Operational','20.00','2.00']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('Div', None,), ('cc', None),
                                     ('expense_type', None),
                                     ('Actual', 'Jan'),
                                     ('Forecast', 'Feb')], )

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df.set_index([('Div', None,), ('cc', None), ('expense_type', None)], inplace=True)
df.loc[:, (['Actual', 'Forecast'], ['Jan', 'Feb'])].melt(ignore_index=False).reset_index()
```

returns

```
  (Div, nan) (cc, nan) (expense_type, nan) variable_0 variable_1  value
0          A         B            Personal     Actual        Jan  10.00
1          A         B         Operational     Actual        Jan  20.00
2          A         B            Personal   Forecast        Feb   1.00
3          A         B         Operational   Forecast        Feb   2.00
```

The columnnames aren't ideal, but this should help you along. somewhat. Note how I used indexing and MultiIndexing to make the melt work.

Comment: Hi, I just added the input dictionary for you.